# dependent list show in templets in Django python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

I want to add dependent list in templets in Django . their are 2 table and the forgin key in 2nd table now I want to show in templets like shown as in image.   i wnat to render  the data as showing in 2nd image
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to render. Can you show the code (models and views) and a picture of what the data would like once rendered?

Comment: I want that 1 list get from main table  which have multiple records after  each records have multiple child which comes under the parent  like shown in post image how would i do it in Django  here you can say as an example like dynamic multi level drop down menu